# Android: Custom List Adapter image, text, sub text and checkbox

Tags: listadapter

first, i'm sorry for my bad english and, maybe, for my stupid issues (i'm newbie).
I want to implement an option panel formatted as a title. 
So here my code:

**listview_item_row.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:contentDescription="option image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
         android:textSize="20sp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/txtSubText"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imgIcon"
         android:layout_below="@id/txtText"
         android:paddingLeft="15dp"
         android:textSize="14sp" />

     <CheckBox
         android:id="@+id/checkBox"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtText" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Row.java**

```
    public class Row {
    public int icon;
    public String text;
    public String subtext;
    public Row(){
        super();
    }

    public Row(int icon, String text ,String subtext) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.text = text;
        this.subtext = subtext;
    }
}
```

**RowAdapter.java**

```
    public class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Row data[] = null;

    public RowAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Row[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myRow = convertView;
        RowHolder holder = null;

        if(myRow == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            myRow = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new RowHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)myRow.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtText = (TextView)myRow.findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            holder.txtSubText = (TextView)myRow.findViewById(R.id.txtSubText);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)myRow.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            myRow.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (RowHolder)myRow.getTag();
        }

        Row row = data[position];
        holder.txtText.setText(row.text);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(row.icon);
        holder.txtSubText.setText(row.subtext);

        return myRow;
    }

    static class RowHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtText;
        TextView txtSubText;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

At now i dont show any checkbox when i start the activity even if i've inflate it. How can i fix this?

Also, if I may take advantage from this question, when I have to implement the onClickListener for checkboxes how can i understand WHICH checkbox was clicked? 
I'll do something like this:

```
...
Row row = data[position];
holder.txtText.setText(row.text);
holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(row.icon);
holder.txtSubText.setText(row.subtext);
holder.check..setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // my code here
        }

    }
});
...
```

I think that "position" is the key but i dont know how can i use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the beginning of the issue!

I use it and it works

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        //Largeur des colonnes
        LargeurCol = (int) ((largeurEcran / 4)-7);
        System.out.println(LargeurCol);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.imageview.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LargeurCol, LargeurCol));
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            holder.checkbox.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = cb.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]), "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    int id;
}
```

The setLayoutParams is not an obligation it's to adapt the row size to the screen.

Comment: Still doesnt work, i tried to re-write all my code implementing "BaseAdapter" as u suggest in ur code but i've just a white screen with only header row visible. I've also modify my code using getSystemService(..) instead getLayoutInflater() (the only difference that i see between 2 codes) but the result is the same: all work well but checkBox wont appear.